# Firebase retrieve data by key

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase node as follows -

```
providers
  -userid1
   --userid : userid1
   --keywords
     ---key1 : true
     ---key2 : true
     ---key3 : true
  -userid2
   --userid : userid2
   --keywords
     ---key1 : true
     ---key4 : true
     ---key5 : true
```

I want to retrieve all the userids that have "key1" in their keywords child.

I tried the following query

```
var ref = new Firebase(url+"/providers")
ref.orderByChild("keywords").equalTo("key1").on("value", function(snapshot){
console.log(snapshot.numChildren());
})
```

Also tried -

```
var ref = new Firebase(url+"/providers")
ref.orderByKey().equalTo("key1").on("value", function(snapshot){
console.log(snapshot.numChildren());
})
```

I get no results. What am I missing in the query?
How are the above two queries different? Both the queries don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `key1` is a key, while `equalTo()` is used to check for values.

The trick is to query for records where they `key1` key has a value of `true`:

```
var ref = new Firebase(url+"/providers")
ref.orderByChild("keywords/key1").equalTo(true).on("value", function(snapshot){
    console.log(snapshot.numChildren());
})
```

Don't forget to add indexes on `keywords/key1`, etc. to your rules.json:

```
"providers": {
  "$uid": {
    ".indexOn": ["keywords/key1", "keywords/key2", "keywords/key3", "keywords/key4", "keywords/key5"]
  }
}
```

You'll probably find that adding such indexes is unmaintainable, which is a good indication that your data structure should be improved. In this case, that can be done by adding a secondary, inverted index that maps from each specific key back to the matching providers:

```
providers
  userid1
    userid : userid1
    keywords
      key1 : true
      key2 : true
      key3 : true
  userid2
    userid : userid2
    keywords
      key1 : true
      key4 : true
      key5 : true
providers_by_keyword:
  key1:
    userid1: true
    userid2: true
  key2:
    userid1: true
  key3:
    userid1: true
  key4:
    userid2: true
  key5:
    userid2: true
```

Now you can execute both operations without a query:

1. get all keywords for `user1`: `ref.child('users/user1/keywords').on(...`
2. get all users for `key1`: `ref.parent().child('providers_by_keyword/key1').on(...`

This approach of creating secondary indexes is known as denormalizing in NoSQL databases. It is described in [Firebase's denormalizing is normal blog post](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html). I also recommend reading this [article about NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).

Comment: Thanks Frank. Great answer, I am still a little blurry on indexing. This query worked for me 
ref.orderByChild("key1").on("value", function(s){
  console.log(s.val());
  });
Yes, you are right, I can probably maintain an inverted index.

Comment: Interesting solution. But you'll run into problems when you start securing the data. Or otherwise as the app gains more user (and the query becomes slower). Denormalizing is the way to go: spend some time reading the articles I linked and experiment with putting what's in there to practice.